# RegEx Pattern not matching if the pattern loaded from property file

Tags: java, regex

In my code I validating mobile number with regex pattern.If i hard code the regex pattern in my code its matching and working as expected.But if i fetch the pattern from Property file its not matching.Below is my code

```
public class RegularExpTest {
    public static final Hashtable<String, String> configDetails = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String str = "+917777777777";

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(System
                    .getProperty("conf.path")
                    + "/webconfiguration.xml"));
            properties.loadFromXML(input);
            if (properties != null) {
                Enumeration<Object> keyString = properties.keys();
                String key = "";
                while (keyString.hasMoreElements()) {
                    key = keyString.nextElement().toString();

                    configDetails.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
                }
            }
            String mobPattern = configDetails.get("MOB.PATTERN");
            Pattern mobilePattern = Pattern.compile(mobPattern);
            if(mobilePattern.matcher(str).matches()) {
                System.out.println("true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
True if I hard code the pattern in code
False if I fetch the pattern from property file
```

Below is my regex

```
^(\\+91)?[789]\\d{9}$
```

Why its not working If I fetch the pattern from property file.
webconfiguration.xml

```
<entry key="MOB.PATTERN">^(\\+91)?[789]\\d{9}$</entry>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Are you escaping backslash in the file?

Comment: the most important information is missing: what is written in the property file? Also could help if you print the content of `mobPattern`.

Comment: <entry key="MOB.PATTERN">^(\\+91)?[789]\\d{9}$</entry> this is how i given the pattern in file

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I have added the file content in question,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the backslash in file.Now its working as expected.Thanks @shmosel.